Origin of phrase "我醉欲眠" - "I'm drunk and would like to sleep"
The phrase "我醉欲眠" (literally: "I'm drunk and would like to sleep" is used to indicate one's sincere and straightforward nature.
I see it in Li Bai's poem "山中与幽人对酌".
Is its current use derived from Li Bai's poem, or it was already in use at the time Li Bai wrote it?

The phrase "我醉欲眠" originates from The Book of Song: Biography of Tao Qian (宋书·陶潜传), written before the time of Li Bai. In the text, Tao Qian (陶潜) says, when he is drunk at a gathering:
貴賤造之者，有酒輒設，潛若先醉，便語客：「我醉欲眠，卿可去。」
You can access the full text here: Full text link.

It's quite accurate. 陶潜(渊明) said it to end his guests' visits; Li Bai used it in his poem.

@r13 Please upvote if you find it accurate! It's a much better indication of support than anything else!
